# How to resolve the segmentation fault issue while working with pointers in c?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    float p1,p2;
    float *x,*y;
    printf("Enter the co-ordinates (x,y) : ");
    scanf("%f%f",p1,p2);
    x = &p1;
    y = &p2;
    printf("The co-ordinates(%f,%f) lies in quadrant ",*(x),*(y));
    if(*x == 0 && *y ==0) {
        printf("It is the origin.");
        return;
    }
    if(*x > 0 && *y > 0){
        printf("1");
    }
    else if(*x < 0 && *y > 0){
        printf("2");
    }
    else if(*x < 0 && *y < 0){
        printf("3");
    }
    else printf("4");
    return ;
}
```

This code is throwing an error "Segmentation Fault".
can anyone help me out ?

I have tried to assign values to normal variables then pointers are assigned to that variable's address.But yet it is throwing the same error.

Comment: The naming and types of  `p1,p2` and `x,y` seems to be reversed, which might confuse your issue, especially as the prompt refers to `x,y`, and I suggest you also move the pointer assignments to be above `scanf`, where their usage is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```c
scanf("%f%f",p1,p2);
```

is wrong. `%f` in `scanf()` expects *pointers* of `float` variable, so it should be

```c
scanf("%f%f",&p1,&p2);
```

Checking for input failure is better.

```c
if (scanf("%f%f",&p1,&p2) != 2){
    puts("failed to read values");
    return;
}
```

Comment: if I use &p1,&p2 in scanf , it will mean that the float value should store at the address of address of the variable.                                 and output will be The co-ordinates(0.000000,0.000000) lies in quadrant 1

Comment: @ArpanS. [No, it won't.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tFNipEMbiszGRT6O)

Comment: yes, it is causing that result only.

Comment: No it won't, `p1,p2` are not pointers, so they don't have an "address of the address of". As commented above, you may well have confused yourself by the choice of variable names.